# Build a web console for Xen domU instances

Tags: console, xen

I want to build a service to provide console access (eg. xm console domain) via a web browser to Xen virtual machines. Does such a program already exist? If not, where should I start?

Slicehost offers this service. I'm just wondering how to go about cloning it or using whatever software that they did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slicehost built their web console using [AjaxTerm](http://antony.lesuisse.org/software/ajaxterm/).